# Setting X-Frame-Options header without changing java

Tags: jetty, x-frame-options

I have a black box application that runs on old obsolete Jetty 7. However, it has been working well since we installed it in 2014, and I need it to continue running. I have been asked to add an X-Frame-Options header to the interface, and every time I try to do this by changing Java I get class incompatibility errors. I can, however, make any changes I like to the JSP files, to web.xml, or to the Jetty configuration files in jetty/etc, but so far I have not found a change that works. I tried adding

<* response.addHeader(“X-FRAME-OPTIONS”, “DENY”); *>

to various JSP files but it doesn't seem to help. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: When you installed it 2014, Jetty 7 was already EOL (End of Life).  You'll need to either edit a servlet, edit (or create) a filter, edit WEB-INF/web.xml, or create a custom Handler.

Comment: Of those, I can edit web.xml (I believe the others will all require Java changes?). Do you have a pointer to an article that shows me what to do? Or is the solution so simple you can post it here?

Comment: editing `WEB-INF/web.xml` alone is insufficient, it has to be paired with changes from servlets or filters (possibly even adding new filters for example)

Comment: You would be better off asking on [jetty-users mailing list](https://accounts.eclipse.org/mailing-list/jetty-users) for help with this old of a Jetty version.  Perhaps you can find someone there that still uses that version of Jetty.